# Nonzero element in ${\rm Hom}_\mathbb{Z}(\prod_{n\geq 2}\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Q})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, homological-algebra

I want to check whether there is a nonzero element in ${\rm Hom}_\mathbb{Z}(\prod_{n\geq 2}\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Q})$. If exists, how to construct such element?

Comment: Is there a nonzero $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z \to \mathbb Q$ for $n \ge 2$?

Comment: @AymanHourieh That doesn't really help. What one has to prove is something about the structure of $\prod_{n\ge2}\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ modulo its torsion subgroup. Note that this product is *not* a torsion group.